# VB 2010 Open Word document and Hide Office Ribbon

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, office-2010

I am able to open a Word document from within my VB 2010 application. I need to hide the MS Office ribbon and set the Show Ruler option to false upon opening the document. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: can you share any code that you have tried?

Comment: Have not tried any code yet...the Word Application Object I created has a lot of properties and methods but I do not see any which lets me say myWordApp.HideRibbon or myWordApp.ShowRuler = False

Comment: the ribbon control is the commandbar .. word.CommandBars collection.. may be you can iterate through all the commandbar in above collection and try to set them to Visible false.. havent tried it.. refer to this msdn link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289518(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I am looking into it...this link takes me to a solution for Visual Studio 2003, in 2010 the library it's requiring is no longer available.  I think it might have been merged into one of the new libraries.  But the CommandBars method is there though.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ribbon `<startFromScratch = "true">` at the begining of the ribbon xml code.  The code might look something like this:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<ribbon startFromScratch="true">

'your code here

</ribbon>
</customUI>
```